# Primefaces: Ajax status stops on redirection to new page

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have **page1.jsf** and **page2.jsf**. Page1 has `<p:ajaxstatus/>` with custom spinner in it .
When an action is  performed on page 1 and the user is redirected to page 2, the spinner starts and stops immediately but page1 remains as it is and after few seconds page2 is loaded and is rendered.

How can I keep the spinner spinning  until page2 is fully rendered.

Comment: Javascript is not really my thing, but if by spinner you mean a "loading" type image/gif, you're probably safer keying into the `onload` javascript event somehow, as this event is only fired after the page has completely loaded. Alternatively, you could stash some javascript at the tail end of the page that unloads the image, with the hope that it will be loaded last

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a `@ViewScoped` bean for page1.

When you redirect to page2, the view is created to page2, and the view scoped bean for page1 is dereferenced/destroyed. Ajax request to that bean are thus ignored.

The only solution that I know of would be setting the bean for `page1` as `@SessionScoped`, but that may affect the behavior of your application.

Comment: Its @session scoped.In fact page1 and page 2 has same  managed bean.

Comment: Then I have less idea of what it can be. Anyway (and it is just a supposition) I would expect that changing the page changes internally the UIViewRoot/ViewState that invalidates subsequent Ajax requests.

Comment: Is there any way I can page forward instead of redirection from my managed bean